# Retrieving user email from discord via CURL

Tags: php, curl, discord

we are converting from Slack to Discord and I created a BOT with the goal of simply querying the user list. While I can get the user list, I am unable to get the user email. As I am still learning does anyone have any advice on getting the user email? Forgive me if this seems basic as I am trying to dive into it.

```
// Get Member details
$url="https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/###";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Authorization: Bot '.$authToken),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user must have set the email visible with Oauth. Otherwise it’s not possible to retrieve it.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.